# How do I sort conditionally by separate columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that keeps track of properties.  I have a column that keeps track of the estimated closing date (col D).  When I enter a date in column D, I have a macro that sorts that row by estimated closing date, and that works just fine.

What I would like to do is have a column that is Actual Closing Date (col K).  When I enter a date in column K, I would like to disregard the sorting by column D, and simply cut the row into which I just entered a closing date, and paste it below all the rows that have only estimated closing dates (so that all the properties that are actually closed sit at the bottom of the spreadsheet, with the most recent closing being the highest up). Below is the macro that automatically sorts by date when I enter one in column D.

```
On Error Resume Next

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("D1").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If

End Sub
```

I've used `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` in another program to find the first row that has data in a particular column, but here I will basically want the second row with data in column K (since the first row with col K populated is the one I need to cut and paste, if you will).

I'm debating structuring it as a cut and paste, in which case the only issues are finding which row to cut and where to insert it, or as basically two sorts, but in a way where only one happens at a time.

---

[image: Sorted by estimated closing date]

---

[image: Sorted by actual closing date (I had to delete col D to demonstrate but ideally it would still be there)]

---

[image: Second closed property sorted appropriately]

Comment: Could you please post a 1) picture of some data 2) the desired result after the function is run? I find it unclear from your worded description

Comment: @Rawrplus does that help?

Comment: In your example images, the "Closed" accounts have no "Estimated Close" and that seems off to me. Will your data really have no 'Estimated Close" when it's closed? Or did you want to delete that item? (I would want to keep it to track if we are meeting Estimates)

Comment: One issue I see is that let's say you have your new K column, then add a new entry and sort by D, it might screw with the "Closed" accounts. How about a separate worksheet for closed accounts?

Comment: Quickest and easiest way I can think of would be to use autofilter then set your range to the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and work with that... Or get the range of cells without autofilter and move that range to the bottom and sort away...

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers it's like that because, as of now, when I add an estimated date, it sorts by estimated date (the behavior I'd like to override); I just deleted those cells to demonstrate.  Also I'd prefer that closed properties stay in the same spreadsheet if possible.